# How can I convert a date format MM-DD-YY HH:MI AM/PM to YYYY-MM-DD in Shell Scripting

Tags: shell, date, unix

I am currently trying to convert a date format using the below command

```
while IFS=$'\t' read -r -a ValArray
do
FILEDATE=${ValArray[0]}
COMPDATE=`date -d  $FILEDATE +'%Y-%m-%d'`
```

I get the following error while trying to dynamically fetch a value from file and compare it with today's date

```
++ read -r -a ValArray
++ FILEDATE='02-11-20 2:25 AM'
+++ date -d 02-11-20 2:25 AM +%Y-%m-%d
date: extra operand `AM'
Try `date --help' for more information.
```

How can I override this and get the date in YYYY-MM-DD format ?

Answer (score 1):

**Using Parameter Expansions**

POSIX shell provides parameter expansions to remove a `substring` from a `string` beginning from the left (front) or right (back) of the string:

```
${string#substring}     Strip shortest match of $substring from front of $string
${string##substring}    Strip longest match of $substring from front of $string
${string%substring}     Strip shortest match of $substring from back of $string
${string%%substring}    Strip longest match of $substring from back of $string
```

The substring can contain normal file globbing, e.g. `'*'`, `'?'`, etc.

In your case (with `f='02-11-20 2:25 AM'`), you can remove the various substrings from the left and right to obtain the month, day, and year. You can then multiply the 2-digit year by `100` to obtain the 4-digit year as follows:

```
f='02-11-20 2:25 AM'
f="${f% *}"     # trim AM (to first space) from right (back)
f="${f% *}"     # trim 2:25 (to first space) from right
m="${f%%-*}"    # trim to last - from right leaving month
y="${f##*-}"    # trim to last - from left (front) leaving year
d="${f#*-}"     # trim to first - from left leaving day-year
d="${d%-*}"     # trim to first - from right leaving day
y=$((y*100))    # mulitply 2-digit year by 100
printf "%4d-%02d-%02d\n" "$y" "$m" "$d"     # output in desired format
```

**Using `expr substr string start length`**

POSIX also provides the old `expr ....` set of string manipulation functions, though since *command substitutions* are involved, it will likely be slower than the built-in parameter expansions. The one relevant here is:

```
expr substr string start length
```

To extract the `length` character substring from `string` beginning at index (1-based) `start`. You can retrieve the month, day and year using:

```
f='02-11-20 2:25 AM'
m=$(expr substr "$f" 1 2)                   # extract 2-digit substring at 1
d=$(expr substr "$f" 4 2)                   # extract 2-digit substring at 4
y=$(expr substr "$f" 7 2)                   # extract 2-digit substring at 7
y=$((y*100))                                # mulitply 2-digit year by 100
printf "%4d-%02d-%02d\n" "$y" "$m" "$d"     # output in desired format
```

(**note:** just as when using `[...]` always quote your variables when using `expr ...`)

**Using `sed`**

You can also use the basic `sed` substitution with three capture groups and three backreferences to reinsert the date components in the correct order. The capture groups `\(text\)` capture the text between them (represented by the *regular expression* `text`) and in the replacement part of the expression the captured text can be reinserted using the numbered backreference `\1` for the first capture, `\2` for he second and so on, e.g.

```
f='02-11-20 2:25 AM'
echo "$f" | sed 's/^\(..\)-\(..\)-\(..\).*$/\300-\1-\2/'
```

**Example Output**

Both approaches produce the same output:

```
2000-02-11
```

Let me know if you have further questions.